# Draw tool in Sculpting mode paints like the brush is highly scattered. Click and hold paints single dots every once in a while. Maybe a bug?

Tags: sculpting, sculpt, tools, draw-mode

I've searched all over and it seems like I'm the only one who has had this problem. I have a sphere with plenty of geometry, no modifiers, and every other sculpting tools works totally fine. However, when I use the draw tool it only applies single dots instead of a steady flow. As far as I can tell, all the default settings are in place. I have no idea what the problem is. Thanks for any help in advance!

[Each dot appears after dragging my mouse around a bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv8Mb.jpg)
[image: Settings for my draw brush]

Comment: Have you tried starting Blender with factory default settings?

Comment: Under Brush Settings -> Stroke, check the Spacing setting - the higher the value the larger the spacing will be between each time the brush is applied during a stroke.

Comment: Apparently it was a bug, I just had to restart my computer and its working fine now. Thanks guys!